# Combinations of a Combination lock

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A 'combination' lock has three numbers, each in the range 1-50.

1. How many have the first and second numbers matching?
2. How many have exactly two of the numbers matching?

All I know is that this a permutation case.

I'm not sure how to find the answer.

Comment: Did tried something?

Comment: i dont know how to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to start the first one : every such combination is of the form $AAB$ where $A,B$ are in the range $1-50$.How many choices for $A$? How many for $B$?(How do you find the answer once you know these values?)  Note that it is okay if $A=B$, we only want to find those for which the first two positions match.

---

To do the second one, we proceed by complementation, instead counting those for which there are no matches, or all three match.

- How many have all three matching ? These are of the form $AAA$, so how many possibilities for $A$?
- Those with none matching have $ABC$ with $A\neq B , B \neq C , A \neq C$. How many choices for $A$? How many choices for $B$, *given* the value of $A$? How many choices for $C$, given the values of both $B$ and $A$? Now multiply all of them.
- Finally add these two and subtract from the total number of possible permutations (how many is that? This is the easiest of the lot).